# Customising django form field rendering

Tags: python, css, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am attempting to customise Django form rendering.

I am rendering my form out into HTML like this:

```
<form action="." method="POST" class="form-group">
    {% csrf_token %}{{ form.non_field_errors }}

    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">

            <br>
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            <br>
            {{ field }}
            <br>

        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit Questionnaire" />
</form>
```

For one of my fields, I have a multiple-choice option which renders the {{ field }} as a "li/ul" tag, hence I get bullet-points next to checkboxes, an example of which is displayed below:

[image: bullet point next to checkbox]

**I am trying to get rid of the bullet point.**

Answer (score 0):

Style the `<ul>` with this:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

This will style all unordered lists, so rather use a custom CSS class.